# How to remove Sweat stains from clothing?

Tags: cleaning, home, clothing, laundry, summer

In the Summer, you will usually sweat a large amount or a little, at least. This is natural, but the stain that results(especially in white clothing) is annoying and unsightly. What can I do to clean the sweat stain out without ruining the clothes?

***I have tried:***

- Washing the clothing several times.
- Adding extra detergent.

*I am looking for a alternative product that does not cost to much.*

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I've found that antiperspirants create stains that are significantly more noticeable than those from the sweat itself.

If you use antiperspirants, perhaps try switching to a deodorant instead as a preventative measure.

As for the clothes, try Vanish Oxi Action (other Sodium Percarbonate based cleaners are available!). It's pretty cheap, and blitzes through most stuff.

[Vanish Stain Solver - Sweat Stain Removal](http://www.vanish.co.uk/stain-solver/other/sweat-stains)

Comment: Do the products you suggest also work on antiperspirant stains, or just sweat stains?

Answer (score 1):

***You could try:***

- Washing the clothing in  lemon juice . Soaking the clothes gives it a better effect. Soak for at least a hour. White Vinegar works, as well.

**Some solutions from [housecleaningcentral.com:](http://www.housecleaningcentral.com/en/cleaning-tips/stain-removal/sweat-perspiration-deodorant.html)**

- Crush 2 aspirin in 1/2 cup of hot water and then put this on the stain. Wait 2-4 hours. After that wash as normal in clothes detergent and repeat if necessary.
- Using dish soap and /or Baking Soda. Baking Soda works, but not that well on the older stains.
- Take 1/4 cup of water and mix with 1/4 cup of ammonia. Put this on the stain and sit for 1 hour. Then wash normally.
- The article says you can use Meat Tenderizers, but I have little experience with them.