# Sweat absorbing ways to improve cosmetic appearances of garments

Tags: clothing, summer

I live in a country where the average monthly temperature is around 29 degrees and it is very humid here. In addition I belong to the group of people who perspire more than average, just leaving the house 5min I would be drenched.

I am already wearing clothes with breathable fabric, but I'm still drenched most of the time. Is there any tactic that anyone knows to reduce my sweating problem that don't have much other bad side effects. (I read that antiperspirants can cause sweat stains [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/how-to-remove-sweat-stains-from-clothing) so using that seems like out of the option for now)

Comment: In your current environment, you probably *don't* want to take steps to reduce your body's ability to perspire.. Evaporation of sweat requires energy, which comes from heat. The side effect is that sweat evaporating cools the surface from where it evaporates -> no evaporation, no cooling -> overheating/heat exhaustion and other undesirable health follow-ons..

Comment: What exactly is the problem? – Please [edit] to clarify: skin problems, cosmetic appearance of garments, shiny forehead, eventual development of smell, overheating something else? You will probably not solve all aspects at once equally well.

Answer (score 1):

I once watched a documentary in which a fashion designer was making stage costumes he had a commission for. He said that although it was not a requirement, he prefers to sew fabric mesh on the inside of the costumes for the sake of performers' comfort (it appeared to be the same thing you can find on inside of some sports suits), because it absorbs the perspiration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the humidity.  No matter the breathability of your clothing, it will end up soaked if your sweat can't evaporate.  The only real solution is to wear as little as required by law/convention.

Answer (score -1):

I had a friend with a sweating problem. His doctor set him up with prescription-grade antiperspirant. It is not something that you can buy in stores in the United States. My friend used it on his back, chest, etc.